# Why bower overrides don't be effective

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, overriding, bower

I'm using bower for bootstrap but don't want all the less files.
So, i'm using a bower.json like this.

    `{
        "name": "webapp",
        "private": true,
        "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
        "modernizr": "~2.8.3"
      },
      "overrides": {
        "bootstrap": {
          "main": [
            "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
            "dist/js/bootstrap.js",
            "dist/fonts/*"
          ],
          "ignore": [
            "less/bootstrap.less"
          ]
        }
      }
    }`

But, it don't work like i'm expecting.
Someone know why ?

Comment: What are you expecting and what actually happens?

Comment: I'm expecting to have only fonts and .css files but i also have  less directory and  other files like gruntfile.js, package.json ...